# How to make a "span" across the diagonal of the browser window?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I have tried to add the "SOLD!" sign across the diagonal of my house-selling web-page. Here is what I tried.
HTML:

```
<span id="prodano">PRODANO! - SOLD!</span>
```

CSS:

```
#prodano
{
    background-color:#FF7777;
    color:#000077;
    font-size:36px;
    line-height:50px;
    position:fixed;
    display:none; /*Has not yet been sold!*/
    text-align:center;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
document.body.onresize=function()
    {
        var content=document.getElementById("content");
        var sirinaProzora=(window.innerWidth || //Moderni internetski preglednici
                            document.documentElement.clientWidth || //Internet Explorer 8
                            document.body.clientWidth //Internet Explorer 6
                            );
        var visinaProzora=(window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight);
        content.style.left=sirinaProzora/2-content.clientWidth/2+"px";
        var prodano=document.getElementById("prodano");
        var sirinaNatpisaProdano=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(sirinaProzora,2)+Math.pow(visinaProzora,2))+2*50;
        prodano.style.width=sirinaNatpisaProdano+"px";
        var nagibNatpisaProdano=Math.atan2(visinaProzora,sirinaProzora);
        prodano.style.transform="rotate("+nagibNatpisaProdano+"rad)";
        var yKoordinataNatpisa=(visinaProzora/2-Math.cos(nagibNatpisaProdano)*50);
        prodano.style.top=yKoordinataNatpisa+"px";
        prodano.style.left=-(Math.sin(nagibNatpisaProdano)*yKoordinataNatpisa)+"px";
    }
window.onresize=document.body.onresize;
window.onload=document.body.onresize;
```

I haven't yet managed to sell my house.
But, anyway, what I have done now works in Firefox when run on my laptop, however, for some reason, it moves away from the diagonal as I resize the window. Can you find the error?
You can see my house-selling web-page [here](https://flatassembler.github.io/Kuce/ivanaGoranaKovacica30.html) (the "display" of that "span" is set to "none" instead of to "block").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like below. The trick is to correctly set the transform origin to make the calculation easy:

```js
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
document.querySelector('#prodano').style.width=Math.sqrt(h*h + w*w)+"px";
document.querySelector('#prodano').style.transform="translateY(-50%)  rotate("+(Math.atan(h/w))+"rad)";

window.onresize = function(event) {
    w = window.innerWidth;
    h = window.innerHeight;
    document.querySelector('#prodano').style.width=Math.sqrt(h*h + w*w)+"px";
    document.querySelector('#prodano').style.transform="translateY(-50%) rotate("+(Math.atan(h/w))+"rad)";
};
```

```css
#prodano {
  background-color: #FF7777;
  color: #000077;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  text-align: center;
  transform-origin:left;
}
```

```html
<span id="prodano">PRODANO! - SOLD!</span>
```

To have the other diagonal we simply use bottom instead of top and invert the transformation

```js
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
document.querySelector('#prodano').style.width=Math.sqrt(h*h + w*w)+"px";
document.querySelector('#prodano').style.transform="translateY(50%)  rotate(-"+(Math.atan(h/w))+"rad)";

window.onresize = function(event) {
    w = window.innerWidth;
    h = window.innerHeight;
    document.querySelector('#prodano').style.width=Math.sqrt(h*h + w*w)+"px";
    document.querySelector('#prodano').style.transform="translateY(50%) rotate(-"+(Math.atan(h/w))+"rad)";
};
```

```css
#prodano {
  background-color: #FF7777;
  color: #000077;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  text-align: center;
  transform-origin:left;
}
```

```html
<span id="prodano">PRODANO! - SOLD!</span>
```